# Samsaung S7 Edge, LCD and glass damaged, turns on but black screen. How to mirror on PC ? without installing anything on the phone

Tags: usb, usb-debugging, screen-mirroring

It`s a S7 Edge sliver T-Mobile smartphone, the LCD and glass is shattered. It turns on and off when the phone is charging, you can see it in charging mode. And when you're turning it on, you can see the startup screen and the boot-up logos. Besides that everything else is working.

Comment: USB Debugging is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's very impossible to that..Unless..

**IF YOU HAVE ALREADY TURNED ON USB DEBUGGING SKIP THESE**

1.) If you have a TV, you need to buy Micro USB to HDMI Adaptor

2.) After connecting Find the HDMI Mode on your TV

3.) Then Turn On Your USB Debugging

> Go to **Settings** > About Phone > Scroll down And find **Build Number**
>   **>** Tap it Seven times > Go back to **Settings** > Developer Options (A new option you will see now) > Scroll down and enable **USB Debugging**

Now that you have enabled **USB Debugging** don't forget to connect you phone to the computer

**In Your Computer**

1.) Download Google Chrome and the Vysor Chrome app. Since Chrome works on Windows, Mac, and Linux, this app will work on all platforms, including Chrome OS, which you should give a chance

2.) Start Vysor from the Chrome App Launcher

3.) Click Find Devices and select your phone

4.) Vysor will start up, and you will see your Android screen on your computer

*Optional: You can set your phone to connect automatically every time the USB cable is plugged into it*

**DONE**

Glad To Help :)